# Что учить, чтобы понять принципы современного программирования?

Tags: ооп, code-style

Здравствуйте, если кратко - сейчас пишу на скриптовых языках, но хочу понять принципы современного программирование, а именно - ООП и т.п, соответствовать тону хорошего кодинга.. Подскажите, с чего начать?! Хочется не вникать в особенности синтаксиса определенных языков, а понять общие принципы.. алгоритмы
Понимаю, что вопрос слишком абстрактен, но возможно Вы посоветуете какую-нибудь литературу/серию статей
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: А может просто пойти на github.com или подобные ресурсы и скачать себе пару-тройку проектов, исследовать их немножко? Попробовать понять, почему и как написано то или другое. А потом браться за умные книги - все будет куда понятнее.

Comment: Эх, ничего себе современное программирование! ООП старше нас с вами, Smalltalk появился до 1980-го года.

Answer (score 5):

Стив Макконнелл - Совершенный код.